# Getting NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I can't seem to figure out what exactly the problem is with Devise during Registration. Do you have an idea of what might be wrong the structure of my user model. I have more than one, so hopefully, I can apply the same solution to the other.

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `authentication_token' for #<User:0x21daf490>):
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
  simple_token_authentication (1.7.0) lib/simple_token_authentication/acts_as_token_authenticatable.rb:22:in `ensure_authentication_token'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
  devise (3.4.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:19:in `create'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  request_store (1.1.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/server.rb:492:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/server.rb:363:in `process_client'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `call'
  puma (2.10.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `block in spawn_thread'


  Rendered C:/Ruby214/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby214/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby214/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby214/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby214/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (54.0ms)

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
  before_create :create_login
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged
  has_many :posts
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :comments
  acts_as_inkwell_user
  attachment :profile_avatar
  attachment :profile_main
  attachment :profile_header
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  acts_as_messageable
  attr_accessor :login
  validates_presence_of :age, :gender
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :message => "Sorry, this username has been taken", length: {in: 4..20}
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => "Sorry, this email is already registered"
  validates_confirmation_of :encrypted_password

  #Devise Username/Email Override
  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

  def create_login
    email = self.email.split(/@/)
    login_taken = User.where( :login => email[0]).first
    unless login_taken
      self.login = email[0]
    else
      self.login = self.email
    end
  end

  def mailboxer_email(object)
    email
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs for simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) (which is where your error is coming from) you have to create the migration to add the field `authentication_token` to your user model:

```
rails g migration add_authentication_token_to_users authentication_token:string:index
rake db:migrate
```

Then restart your server and the error should be gone.

Comment: I didn't see your answer until now. But, thank you, I looked closely at the console, and then realized that simple_token wasn't completely installed into my db and system. I must have been rushing and forgot to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to add the migrations for gem 'simple_token_authentication', '~> 1.0' by mistake.

```
acts_as_token_authenticatable

rails g migration add_authentication_token_to_users authentication_token:string:index
rake db:migrate
```